# CentOS 6.6, почему не получается настроить сеть?

Tags: centos, сеть, vmware

Не могу установить сеть в CentOS 6.6 minimum. Ос устанавливается на виртуальную машину VMware. До установки CentOS 6.6. на эту машину устанавливалась CentOS 7, и сеть настроилась во время инсталляции без проблем. Когда же я установил Centos 6.6 и указал все те же адреса, сеть настроить не получилось. Пробовал настраивать сеть во время инсталляции ОС и после. В настройках сети указывал ip, dns, netmask, gateway и mac адреса. Пробовал делать yum update и пинговать google, результаты на скрине:
[image: CentOS network]

Comment: Судя по тегу `vmware` используется виртуальная машина. Вы уверены в настройках `vmware`?

Comment: Посмотрите, идет ли ping на host (саму vmware) по его IP. / И вообще, покажите вывод ifconfig -a

Comment: Верно ОС ставится на виртуальную машину. Но на эту же машину я ставил CentOS 7, и сеть настроилась сразу. Так я сделал вывод, что настройки vmware правильные. Затем подключил к машине другой виртуальны диск, на который установил CentOS 6.6 и не смог настроить сеть. Так я сделал вывод, что настройки виртуальной машины все же верны, и дело в настройках ОС. Я правильно мыслю, или тут я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Если я пишу # ping x.x.x.x (айпи хоста vmware), то выдается сообщение  "connect: Network is unreachable"

Comment: вывод ifconfig -a http://rghost.ru/7Jf8KhSJW/image.png

Comment: А что-nо маска у eth0 странная. IMHO обычно 255.255.255.0

Comment: Вы уже решили вашу проблему? У вас маска странная. Насколько я помню, это глобальный широковещательный адрес. Попробуйте сменить маску на `255.255.255.0`.

Answer (score 1):

судя по меткам, centos устанавливается как клиент в vmware. обычно в системах виртуализации для виртуальных машин принято использовать авто-конфигурирование сети с помощью dhcp.

попробуйте пойти этим, наиболее распространённым и простым путём.

Comment: Вы говорите об автоконфигурации настроек самой vmware или настроек CentOS ?

Comment: я говорю об автоконфигурации сетевых настроек гостевой виртуальной машины. в комментарии к другому ответу вы написали, что другая установка у вас прошла успешно. сравните настройки vmware для сети у этих двух виртуальных машин. возможно, они отличаются, или, к примеру, в настройках есть привязка к mac-адресу гостевой системы.